# Set default value where blank in array data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm fetching data in an array like this

```
[
    {
        "Id": 111,
        "Name": "Test 1",
        "Email": "email1@domain.net",
    },
    {
        "Id": 133,
        "Name": "Test 2",
        "Email": "null",
    },
    {
        "Id": 133,
        "Name": null,
        "Email": "email2@domain.net",
    }
]
```

from api

```
 this.Details = response;
```

i want to replace the value of null or blank with `-`.

Comment: You can probably use the nullish coalescing operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing Edit: Pertaining to the code sample you had in your question earlier -> `{{ row.Name ?? "No name"}}`

Comment: "null" or null or both

Answer (score -1):

You can do a conditional operator like `&&`

```
data[0].Name && console.log("There is a Name at 0");
data[1].Name && console.log("There is a Name at 1");
data[2].Name && console.log("There is a Name at 2");
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        "Id": 111,
        "Name": "Test 1",
        "Email": "email1@domain.net",
    },
    {
        "Id": 133,
        "Name": "Test 2",
        "Email": "null",
    },
    {
        "Id": 133,
        "Name": null,
        "Email": "email2@domain.net",
    }
]


data[0].Name && console.log("There is a Name at 0");
data[1].Name && console.log("There is a Name at 1");
data[2].Name && console.log("There is a Name at 2");
```